# How do I configure OpsWorks to deploy a not-officially-supported version of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am trying to set up an OpsWorks stack to with a Node.js layer that uses the latest version of Node (4.1.1). I am fairly new to Chef and I am not sure where in the cookbooks repo I would need to make changes to pull down and install Node 4.1.1, instead of their default which is 0.12.7.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is a nodejs cookbook in the chef supermarket. did you try that? https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nodejs

Comment: I looked at that but it looks like it is set to deploy an old version of Node. I have tried changing the AWS-provided Chef recipe to pull 4.1.1. The problem is that it calls to an Amazon-owned repository and they haven't added that version to their repo. And I don't really know enough Chef to start my own from scratch.

Comment: You may need to try the nodejs recipe on supermarket inside a wrapper cookbook with an attribute to set the correct version. Please comment here on how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

2 things need to happen:

- you need a custom layer
- you need to pull in a recipe/cookbook that contains the newer nodejs

The easiest way to do this is to use berkshelf as outlined here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/cookbooks-101-opsworks-berkshelf.html#opsworks-berkshelf-opsworks

In the berksfile add the supermarket.chef.io as a source and the nodejs as a recipe.

You can specify the node version in the opsworks stack config.
Use the recipe in the custom layer and you should be set.